# how to change default persian fonts in arch

Tags: linux, fonts, archlinux, farsi

I'm new at arch and have a big problem with it and it's Persian fonts are very ugly!

[image: I inserted an image for example here]

This is in all applications (chrome ,games ,gnome menu etc.).

What I can to do ?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` (create if not exist)
copy this code and save > for change default font to **Vazirmatn** (persian font) :

```
 <?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>

 <match>
  <edit mode="prepend" name="family">
   <string>Vazirmatn</string>
  </edit>
 </match>

 <dir>~/.local/share/fonts</dir>
 <dir>/usr/share/fonts/</dir>

</fontconfig>
```

**Vazirmatn** must copied to ~/.fonts before .